# What is the overhead on a 3g connection to keep a socket open indefinitely

Tags: tcp, cellular-network

In order to keep a tcp/ip socket open on a cellular network, does the phone have to keep sending data?

On a tcp/ip over ethernet, you can just open the socket send a keep alive once in a while.

Is tcp/ip over 3g ay different?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat. Most cell phones don't have a fixed IP address when on 3G, especially when moving around, so your connections may end up dropped once in a while, even if connectivity is otherwise fine.

Answer (score -1):

No, the TCP/IP on the 3G it's the same old TCP/IP you know. You can send the keep alive messages to sustain the connection.

Remember that the 3G is on the 2 bottom layers of the protocol list, so the TCP/IP is independent from the other layers.